# Best way to use ERB 'in browser' similar to opening an html in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, erb

I have a program at work that everyone can access via an index.html shortcut. They access the file through File Explorer. I want to embed some Ruby and render it via html, but without going through Rails/Sinatra since that would require actually a) hosting the site or b) running it on a server every time to access it.

I want my co-workers to be able to simply double-click the `index.html` shortcut and it pop up in their browser as it does now. BUT with embedded ruby so that I can add some different functionality beyond html/css.

Is this possible? If so, best route?

Comment: is this file on a network drive? Or you distribute it to end users?

Comment: How dynamic you need this to be? Maybe static site generators will do? (jekyll, for example)

Comment: It is on Microsoft Sharepoint via File Explorer. All co-workers have access to SharePoint.

Comment: I primarily want to add forms to it - allow users to post to a page and then delete from the page as well. I'm not familiar with Jekyll

Comment: So, you want to have a database too? Might as well create a real app. Will go much more smoothly.

Comment: You're probably right. Given that I'm the only one working on this project, launching it would require adding a variety of other features. Since this is only used amongst coworkers there would then need to be security measures put in place to keep it local to the office - which SharePoint and FileExplorer does well. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the `.erb` templating engine you'll have to make sure that the server that serves the HTML page has Ruby installed, as well as some HTTP routing mechanism that responds to the request, processes the embedded Ruby, and renders the HTML result.

So to answer your question, if you want to use `ERB`, you will have to install Ruby on your web server at bare minimum.

You would save yourself a lot of time by using a minimal framework like Sinatra, but it is possible to build something from scratch in pure Ruby, since the `ERB` class is included in Ruby core.

Not sure how dynamic you need the page to be, or how much user input alters the page, but you may be able to do what you need with a combination of JavaScript/cookies/localstorage.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Given that I work with non-techies is there a workaround besides actually launching the site? Most of them have never seen a command line, so I can't ask them to `shotgun` and use Sinatra. Is using Ruby's `erb` class pretty much it?

Comment: May be you're looking at the wrong language? Like @pennypacker said, Ruby requires you to run a server component. But since JavaScript is shipped in all browsers, may be build your solution around that? It has libraries for templating like what ERB does; for example, Mustache or Handlebars. Will that work?